# Python doc strings print \n instead of a new line (Python 2.7.5 on a Mac)

Tags: python, macos, docstring

So here is what I am typing

```
>>> list = [1,2,3]
>>> list.__doc__
"list() -> new empty list\nlist(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items"
```

The problem being that it literally prints "\n" instead of printing a new line, making more complicated doc strings almost impossible to read.

The same thing happens with all of the other built-in classes I have tried.

The version information I get from python when I open it is:
    Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul 16 2013, 14:23:29) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is because the `list.__doc__` is a string.

When you just type `list.__doc__` you will get the contents like this :

```
>>> list.__doc__
"list() -> new empty list\nlist(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items"
```

However if you type `print list.__doc__`

```
>>> print list.__doc__
list() -> new empty list
list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
```

So the print function properly formats the string to include the linebreak.

Hope that helps :)